# Better Static Analysis

Tags: variables, warning

What options are there for enhancing static analysis of emacs lisp code? Either via builtin flags or third party packages?

I'm mainly referring to unused packages/modules and requires.

I'm aware of that Emacs master has recently acquired inference of function types.